# Death Wind and Irradiate are able to send indestructible creatures to the Graveyard?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-indestructible

Cards like [Death Wind](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDeath%20Wind%5d) or [Irradiate](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bIrradiate%5d) are able to destroy a creature, also preventing any creature's regeneration ability.
But, obviously, both of them are not able to send to the graveyard a creature with indestructible, probably because their effect ends at the end of the turn, as indicated by the text of the two cards, too.

The situation is different when a creature with indestructible, for example [Ulamog, the Infinite Gyre](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUlamog%2c%20the%20Infinite%20Gyre%5d), has several -1/-1 counters, which in the end lead the creature in question to permanently have a value 0 for its toughness.

For example, when Ulamog has 10 or more -1/-1 counters on it, due to a card like [Soul-Scar Mage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSoul-Scar%20Mage%5d), Ulamog will go to the graveyard.

This last strategy seems to be one of the rare solutions capable of killing a creature with indestructible.

Without prejudice to the obvious differences between the two types of cards that are capable of giving -X/-X to creatures, however, some analogies remain.

Assuming that the above is all correct - since it is likely that it may not be so at all - then the question is as follows:

What is the reason - strictly technical - that allows the -X/-X counters to send an indestructible creature to the graveyard, while a -X/-X effect that lasts until the end of turn is not able to do this?

Comment: Ok...I really didn't think that,to get rid of an indestructible creature,was enough a spell that is able to assign -X/-X until the end of the turn to it.I thought it would take X -0 / -1 counters to send it to the cemetery ... Obviously, in these conditions my question is wrong from the beginning, and there is nothing "strictly technical" to find for understand what was right from the start. But I leave my wrong questions anyway, I don't delete them or change their essential parts...as someone does everytime he has something to hide...

Comment: I was deceived by an internet page where it was said that one of the only ways to send an indestructible creature to the cemetery is to assign it many -0 / -1 counters, so as to permanently bring its constitution to 0, and not only until the end of turn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Assuming that the above is all correct

Unfortunately, it's not. There are several ways for state-based actions to put a creature into its owner's graveyard; the ones relevant for this situation are:

> 704.5f If a creature has toughness 0 or less, it’s put into its owner’s graveyard. Regeneration can’t replace this event.
>
> 704.5g If a creature has toughness greater than 0, and the total damage marked on it is greater than or equal to its toughness, that creature has been dealt lethal damage and is destroyed. Regeneration can replace this event.

Indestructible only prevents the latter:

> 702.12b A permanent with indestructible can’t be destroyed. Such permanents aren’t destroyed by lethal damage, and they ignore the state-based action that checks for lethal damage (see rule 704.5g).

So Death Wind and Irradiate *are* able to kill indestructible creatures. They don't 'destroy' creatures like [Terror](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=16624) does; that card *doesn't* work against indestructible creatures.

Another option to combat indestructible creatures is to exile them instead. White has some options for this like [Swords to Plowshares](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSwords%20to%20Plowshares%5d) and [Path to Exile](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPath%20to%20Exile%5d).

Comment: @Massimiliano Thank you. Finding duplicates can be hard, the automated system isn't always good at it. Most of the times, the [search](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/search) does a better job. Duplicates can be useful as signposts: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304192/295232 so don't worry about having asked one.

Comment: Anyway, it is still true that -1/-1 counters works well against indestructible creatures, just like Death Wind and Irradiate do. It must be true even more so.

Comment: @Massimiliano -1/-1 counters are just counters that give the creature -1/-1. That's the same kind of "gives the creature -1/-1" that Death Wind would do at X=1. There's nothing special about the counters here, it's just the effects of dropping a creature to 0 toughness.

Comment: No,in fact everything is now much clearer. I was deceived by an internet page where it was said that one of the only ways to send an indestructible creature to the cemetery is to assign it many -0 / -1 counters, so as to permanently bring its constitution to 0, and not only until the end of turn. Thanks to your answer, in fact, everything returns, and no "technical" explanation is needed to clarify this fact.Well,you can also make fun of me with the "stricktly technical" thing!This time it is right to do it;not as in the case of the unfair duplication concerning negative enchantments